# Is there a way of finding solubility/solvent from basic information?

Tags: solubility, theoretical-chemistry

Let's say I have a compound and I want to find a solvent for it.

Looking on some where like Wikipedia, it is quite easy to find solubility, in various solvents for common compounds. However it can be quite lacking for less well know compounds (For example [Glycin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycin)).

Although one can quite often find a list of some basic metrics (Polarizability,  log D, etc) for the compound. Say on:
[Chemspider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.60494.html#)

Given those basic metrics is it possible to infer what some likely solvents would be? Or What would be the name of those techniques?

*Assuming normal temperature and pressure etc

Comment: The CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics is a good source of info like this.  It lists solubility info for many compounds.

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad question as solubility equally depends e.g., on the temperature of the solvent(s), presence of other (already dissolved) compounds. A database like [Reaxys](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/reaxys) used by research institutes may indicate the publications with these (measured) values, or contain these values itself. Based on known data, programs may be trained to anticipate solubility of unknowns based on a structure drawn. E.g., for X in water [background](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/scripts/MarvinWeb/help/calculations/solubility.html) of a relevant program, [Marvin](https://chemaxon.com/products/marvin), in function of the pH value, or an implementation of [ESOL](https://github.com/PatWalters/solubility).